# boost split usage

Tags: c++, string, boost, split

I have a string of format `[id1,id2,id3]`. i'm using boost split to split the string and fill it in a vector.

```
boost::split(ids, message, boost::is_any_of("[, ]"));
```

ids is my vector declared as `std::vector<std::string> ids`.

now only the odd indices of the vector contains the ids, the even ones are empty. can anyone tell me what could be the reason and how to fix it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
boost::algorithm::split( ids, message, boost::is_any_of("[, ]"),
                         boost::algorithm::token_compress_on );
```

Comment: Reformatted for clarity. A simple sentence would not be amiss :)

Comment: Thanks, the intermediate empty entries are gone, but still the first and last entries are empty.

Comment: @Manoj: I tried it with several cases, the boost's split treat the delim as seperators, if the seperator occur at the beginning, it will create a 0 length string. It is similar when seperator occur at the end.